# Android - Create notification bar effect with a View

Tags: android, image, view

I wanna create a effect in my app based on notified bar on android, I wanna hide the activity in some moments when the user drop the "bar" from left to right, and inverse, I think that is possible create a view of the same size of the screen (fullscreen) and put over the activity out the screen (for right) and drag it to left to hide the activity.

The "bar" is only a black background. Any ideas? thanks